# Getting constant accuracies for training and validation sets despite their losses are changing during CNN training?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

As the title clearly describes the issue I've been experiencing during the training of my CNN model, the accuracies of training and validation sets are constant despite the losses of them are changing. I have included the detail regarding the model and its training setup below. What may cause this issue?

Here is the data that was used by training (`X_train` & `y_train`), validation, and test sets (`X_test` and `y_test`):

```
df = pd.read_csv(CSV_PATH, sep=',', header=None)
print(f'Shape of all data: {df.shape}')
    
y = df.iloc[:, -1].values
X = df.iloc[:, :-1].values

encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(y)
encoded_Y = encoder.transform(y)
dummy_y = to_categorical(encoded_Y)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, dummy_y, test_size=0.3, random_state=RANDOM_STATE)

X_train = X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1))
X_test = X_test.reshape((X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], 1))
```

Here are the shapes of training and test sets:

```
Shape of X_train: (1322, 10800, 1)
Shape of Y_train: (1322, 3)
Shape of X_test: (567, 10800, 1)
Shape of y_test: (567, 3)
```

Here is my CNN model:

```
# Model hyper-parameters
activation_fn = 'relu'
n_lr = 1e-4
weight_decay = 1e-4
batch_size = 64
num_epochs = 200*10*10
num_classes = 3
n_dropout = 0.6
n_momentum = 0.5
n_kernel = 5
n_reg = 1e-5

# the sequential model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(128, n_kernel, input_shape=(10800, 1)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation(activation_fn))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=2))

model.add(Dropout(n_dropout))

model.add(Conv1D(256, n_kernel))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation(activation_fn))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=2))

model.add(Dropout(n_dropout))

model.add(GlobalAveragePooling1D()) # have tried model.add(Flatten()) as well

model.add(Dense(256, activation=activation_fn))
model.add(Dropout(n_dropout))
model.add(Dense(64, activation=activation_fn))
model.add(Dropout(n_dropout))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

adam = Adam(lr=n_lr, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=weight_decay)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=adam, metrics=['acc'])
```

Here is how I have evaluated the model:

```
Y_pred = model.predict(X_test, verbose=0)
y_pred = np.argmax(Y_pred, axis=1)
y_test_int = np.argmax(y_test, axis=1)
```

And, my model always predicts the same class of three classes during the model evaluation as you can see from the classification result below (via `classification_result(y_test_int, y_pred)` function):

```
          precision    recall  f1-score   support

  normal      0.743     1.000     0.852       421
     apb      0.000     0.000     0.000        45
     pvc      0.000     0.000     0.000       101
```

The model was trained using the `EarlyStopping` callback of `Keras`. Thus, the training has continued for `4,173` epochs. Here is the obtained losses during the training for training and validation sets:

[image: loss]

Here are the obtained accuracies during the training for training and validation sets:

[image: accuracy]

The model was implemented using `Keras` and hosted on Google Colab.

Comment: Why are you applying to_categorical to the predictions?

Comment: For the same reason I do for the training data: to convert labels, the integers, to dummy data. Should not I apply this conversion? @Dr.Snoopy

Comment: No, class predictions are compared as integers ID, not one hot encoded ones.

Comment: But, when I do not apply this conversion during the prediction, I get this error: `ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multilabel-indicator and binary targets`

Comment: And, if I remove the `to_categorical` conversion from the training data as well, this time I get this error: `ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 3) are incompatible`

Comment: I am talking about to_categorical in the predictions, not the labels. To evaluate the model with classification_report, both your labels and predictions need to be integers, not one-hot encoded.

Comment: Many thanks for your care but when I remove the `to_categorical` call in the predictions, I get this error: `ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multilabel-indicator and binary targets`. Could you please post the changes I need to apply as an answer? And, the accuracies are still constant with this modification.

Comment: You also need to apply argmax operation to the labels if you want to compare them within the confusion matrix.

Comment: Yes, argmax will take a one-hot encoded label and transform it to an integer, its effectively the opposite operation of to_categorical.

Comment: Yes, `y_pred = np.argmax(Y_pred, axis=1)` is still there - I just removed the `to_categorical` under the `argmax`. @Frightera

Comment: No, we are talking about argmax to your labels (after training).

Comment: What we meant is, your **true labels** are still one-hot-encoded, apply argmax on them in order to compare with predictions.

Comment: Many thanks to both of you - just edited the OP. But the accuracies are still constant, and all predictions are for the same class, `normal` class. @Frightera @Dr. Snoopy

Comment: That's something about the model, it might be that model just reached its peak capability and can not learn any more information/feature. I'd play with the model architecture by adding some conv layers. And if the dataset is imbalanced I'd try sample weights.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendations. To be honest, I've tried both of them; but did not improve its classification performance even I trained the model for `4,173` epochs as its result is presented in the OP. The odd thing rather than its obtained accuracy is that all predictions are from the same class despite utilizing the class weights (the model in the OP utilizes it as well). @Frightera

Comment: Are you sure that there is not something wrong with the data? Seems like the model can not learn the other classes. What does that data consist of?

Comment: Many thanks for your care. The data is a ECG dataset that consists of 1,889 ECG records where each record consists of 30-s segments and each segment consists of 360 samples. Therefore, the shape of each `X` record is `(10800, 1)`. `y` labels contains 3 classes, namely, `normal`, `apb`, and `pvc`. @Frightera

Comment: I see, I'd also try RNNs to see if there will be a change in predictions. If they still do not change, I would start thinking something can be wrong with the data. Because I can not see anything *wrong* with the CNN model.

Comment: Can you please specify the actual number of samples for each class? Have you tried oversampling instead of assigning class weights? For me, it also looks like there is a problem with the data.

Comment: Sure, the numbers of samples are `1,421`, `133`, and `335` for the `normal`, `apb`, and `pvc` class, respectively. No, I have not tried oversampling to keep the standard dataset as I'm going to compare the performance of my model with the others in the literature. @IvanK.

Answer (score 0):

Although such issues are difficult to resolve without the data, there are a couple of general rules applicable.

The very first thing we do when the model does not seem to learn anything, like here (despite the mild drop in the loss), is to **remove all dropout**.

In fact, dropout is not supposed to be used by default; its nominal function is to guard against overfitting - but of course, before starting to worry about *over*fitting, you must first have some success with *fitting*, something that is clearly not happening here. The fact that, with a dropout rate of `n_dropout = 0.6`, you also seem to be rather too aggressive in its use, does not help, either.

Comment: I've removed all `Dropout` layers, but the situation is still the same.